# MIDL: Proper syntax for outputting namespaces for user defined types / enums?

Tags: c++, namespaces, header-files, generated-code, midl

I took my .NET assembly, used OleView to generate the IDL file, now using

```
midl /header MyAssembly.h MyAssembly.tlb
```

to generate a header file for use in a really old COM project.

Now, MyAssembly.dll references MyAssembly.Core.dll - so I created an IDL file for MyAssembly.Core.dll as well as mscorlib.dll, and have successfully generated my .i_c and .h files from midl for all three.

The problem is that the .h files don't include any namespacing!  I'm getting output like this:

```
virtual /* [id] */ HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE DoThing( 
        /* [in] */ MyEnums MyEnum) = 0;
```

when I'm expecting to see:

```
virtual /* [id] */ HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE DoThing( 
        /* [in] */ MyAssembly_Core::MyEnums MyEnum) = 0;
```

MyAssembly.idl:

```
import "MyAssembly.Core.idl";
[
    uuid(1ED54182-DF43-4FF4-9887-1C105E50427D),
    version(1.0),
    custom(90883F05-3D28-11D2-8F17-00A0C9A6186D, "MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, 
    Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")
]
library MyAssembly
{
    // TLib :     // TLib :  : {515919C5-1821-44B6-8B7A-C42045E2483A}
    importlib("MyAssembly.Core.tlb");
    // TLib : mscorlib.dll : {BED7F4EA-1A96-11D2-8F08-00A0C9A6186D}
    importlib("mscorlib.tlb");
    // TLib : OLE Automation : {00020430-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");
(the rest of the idl)
```

And MyAssembly.Core.dll:

```
import "mscorlib.idl";
[
    uuid(515919C5-1821-44B6-8B7A-C42045E2483A),
    version(1.0),
    custom(90883F05-3D28-11D2-8F17-00A0C9A6186D, "MyAssembly.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")
]
library MyAssembly_Core
{
    // TLib :     // TLib : mscorlib.dll : {BED7F4EA-1A96-11D2-8F08-00A0C9A6186D}
    importlib("mscorlib.tlb");
    // TLib : OLE Automation : {00020430-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");

    typedef [uuid(E01EAD76-4F8F-4B76-AF58-FCC03609EB61), version(1.0),
    custom(0F21F359-AB84-41E8-9A78-36D110E6D2F9, "MyAssembly.Core.MyEnums")
    ]
        enum {
        MyEnum_UNKNOWN = 0xffffffff,
        MyEnum_One = 1,
        MyEnum_Two = 2
    } MyEnums;
(the rest of the idl)
```

Finally, mscorlib.idl:

```
#if (__midl >= 800)
    midl_pragma warning(disable: 2362)
#endif 

[
    uuid(BED7F4EA-1A96-11D2-8F08-00A0C9A6186D),
    version(2.4),
    helpstring("mscorlib.dll"),
    custom(90883F05-3D28-11D2-8F17-00A0C9A6186D, "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089")
]
library mscorlib
{
    // TLib :     // TLib : OLE Automation : {00020430-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");
(the rest of the idl)
```

I'm missing something here, I'm just not sure what.

So how does one have an IDL generate correct namespaces for the output header files?

Thanks,